# Start playing MPMusicPlayerController when app is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to start playing 'MPMusicPlayerController' when the app is in a background state? I have an alarm clock app and I would like to start playing music when the alarm goes off and the app isn't in the foreground.

Comment: Did you end up getting this working?

Answer (score 1):

Go to project properties -> Capabilities and switch on the Application Background Modes

[image]

Then in your plist file add the following key:

[image]

Now just play the music in when your timer sets off.

Comment: Do I just play the music normally? I don't think its working.

Comment: Make sure you do not make any change in the UI while the application is in background. Any change in the UI or OpenGL will cause the application to terminate immediately.